# Callback or real-time communication for social table api

Tags: social-tables

I am evaluating social table API to see if there's any way to get notified when data in the social tablet side changes so that we can sync the data in real time.  I can't find anything on call back or long running operations.  Does that mean polling is the only option?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real time API for Social Tables. This means that you're correct in that polling is the only option for keeping data in sync.